# Hide dynamically created button by clicking on it

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, coffeescript, django-1.8

In my Django project I have a ajax search which returns a list of results along with button "Add"

What I want:

1. Click "Add"
2. Result is added to div on page
3. Button "Add" disappears

Work p. 1-2 but not 3

**jquery-ajax**

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-add', ->
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid")
    title = $(this).attr("data-title")
    url = $(this).attr("data-url")
    $.get('/test/auto_add_page/', {category_id:catid, title:title, url:url}, (data) ->
        $('#pages').html(data)
        $(this).hide()
        ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the `get` now refers to a different object. Save it in a variable in the outer block and refer to that.

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-add', ->
    button = $(this)
    catid = button.attr("data-catid")
    title = button.attr("data-title")
    url = button.attr("data-url")
    $.get('/test/auto_add_page/', {category_id:catid, title:title, url:url}, (data) ->
        $('#pages').html(data)
        button.hide()
    ))
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Intuitively I get where I was wrong, but what object does 'this inside get' refers to?

Comment: Good question. Some experimentation implies it's the [jQuery Ajax settings object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).